# Open two URLs at once when open one url?

Tags: javascript, java, php

Hello and thanks for great answers

I have two websites one for posts and reviews and the other one is store website when visitors open posts website they don't notice store website

I want to take advantage of posts website audience by viewing store website automatically when someone visit posts website 
So visitors open posts website the store website open automatically in another tab in browser   How to do this modification using php or java?
 Update

This very hard to done cause this means that you will bypass the giants. Chrome and safari.., to force the open of the other page as separate page

Comment: What you tried?

Comment: Just stick a banner on your *posts* website and let the user's decide whether they're interested or not - don't try and ram it down their throats, you'll only annoy people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works but will be blocked by popup blockers

```js
<a class="double-web-pages">open two websites</a>

<script>
document.querySelector("a.double-web-pages").addEventListener("click",function(){
  window.open("https://www.storewebsite.com");
  window.open("https://www.postswebsite.com");
})
</script>
```

and this one will open one new tab with store page and replace the current   page with posts page

```js
<a href="https://www.postswebsite.com" class="double-web-pages">open two websites</a>

<script>
document.querySelector("a.double-web-pages").addEventListener("click",function(){
  window.open("https://www.storewebsite.com");
});
</script>
```